# How to melt or reshape a data frame by retaining a desired column

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2, melt

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- structure(c("0.1620678925564", "-0.0609851972808482", "-0.101082695275552",
"0.184268723991321", "-0.0899021067853178", "-0.0943666172060028",
"-0.0531973808347148", "0.0213528550009522", "0.0318445258337625",
"0.0179790366380429", "0.00347902775389391", "-0.0214580643919368",
"-0.0760171167711921", "0.0344372228755224", "0.0415798938956697",
"-0.114239469843063", "0.0217218301803764", "0.0925176396626868",
"-0.0100499090500894", "0.0131491664210288", "-0.00309925737093941",
"0.101206058442775", "0.0231964804556542", "-0.124402538898429",
"0.0753224665976433", "-0.0323083061719772", "-0.0430141604256661",
"-0.0654080281579984", "0.0124273486220488", "0.0529806795359496",
"-0.0390251373720762", "-0.0115216989414941", "0.0505468363135703",
"0.0321298528741327", "-0.0151866963239294", "-0.0169431565502034",
"0.0288166559498562", "-0.0173984873138801", "-0.0114181686359761",
"-0.0176892628883129", "-0.0235673738231865", "0.0412566367114994",
"LAIV D0", "LAIV D3", "LAIV D7", "LAIV D0", "LAIV D3", "LAIV D7"
), .Dim = c(6L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
"6"), c("Neutrophil", "Tcell", "Monocyte", "Bcell", "NKcell",
"PlasmaCell", "DendriticCell", "samples")))
```

It looks like this:

```
  Neutrophil            Tcell                 Monocyte              Bcell                  NKcell                PlasmaCell           
1 "0.1620678925564"     "-0.0531973808347148" "-0.0760171167711921" "-0.0100499090500894"  "0.0753224665976433"  "-0.0390251373720762"
2 "-0.0609851972808482" "0.0213528550009522"  "0.0344372228755224"  "0.0131491664210288"   "-0.0323083061719772" "-0.0115216989414941"
3 "-0.101082695275552"  "0.0318445258337625"  "0.0415798938956697"  "-0.00309925737093941" "-0.0430141604256661" "0.0505468363135703" 
4 "0.184268723991321"   "0.0179790366380429"  "-0.114239469843063"  "0.101206058442775"    "-0.0654080281579984" "0.0321298528741327" 
5 "-0.0899021067853178" "0.00347902775389391" "0.0217218301803764"  "0.0231964804556542"   "0.0124273486220488"  "-0.0151866963239294"
6 "-0.0943666172060028" "-0.0214580643919368" "0.0925176396626868"  "-0.124402538898429"   "0.0529806795359496"  "-0.0169431565502034"
  DendriticCell         samples  
1 "0.0288166559498562"  "LAIV D0"
2 "-0.0173984873138801" "LAIV D3"
3 "-0.0114181686359761" "LAIV D7"
4 "-0.0176892628883129" "LAIV D0"
5 "-0.0235673738231865" "LAIV D3"
6 "0.0412566367114994"  "LAIV D7"
```

What I want to do is to melt it so that it looks like this:

```
   X1            X2                value
1   'LAIV D0'    Neutrophil      0.1620678925564
2   'LAIV D3'    Neutrophil  -0.0609851972808482
....
```

How can I do that?

I tried this  but won't do.

```
library(reshape2)
melt(df)
```

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
df <- as.data.frame.matrix(df)
melt(data = df,id.vars = c("samples"))
```

It will work for both the packages `reshape` and `reshape2`

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `gather` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
as.data.frame(df) %>% 
        gather(Var, Val, -samples)
```